# Count how many words from a list appear in a cell

Tags: excel

I have a column of word game answers people have given, and a list of all the possible right answers. I'm trying to figure out how I can get excel to count how many of the words from the right-answers list appear in each person's response cell.

So, column A contains people's response data, like this:

```
glare, lake, car
rag, clear, gear, lear, cake, glare, rack, keg, car, care, leak, ace
cake, lake, lark, car, rake, cage, real, ekl, rage
Leak, Rage, Gale, Kale, Rag, Lag, Large, Lack, Real, Rake, Race, Car, Care, Leg, Cage
```

And here's the list of all the right answers:

```
grackle, calker, lacker, rackle, argle, cager, carle, clear, clerk, crake, creak, glace, glare, grace, lacer, lager, laker, large, regal, acre, ager, alec, cage, cake, calk, care, cark, carl, clag, crag, earl, egal, gale, gear, geck, kale, lace, lack, lake, lark, leak, lear, race, rack, rage, rake, rale, real, reck, ace, age, ale, arc, are, ark, car, cel, ear, elk, era, erg, gae, gal, gar, gel, kae, kea, keg, lac, lag, lar, lea, leg, lek, rag, rec, reg
```

So, the 1st person wrote in 3 right answers, so B1 should say "3", B2 should say "12", B3 should say "8" (not "9" since "ekl" is not on the list of right answers), and so on.

I'm assuming that this is best done with a macro rather than a formula, but I really don't know where to start so any help would be amazingly appreciated. It doesn't matter to me if the solution is macro- or formula-based. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, all that data is only inside _Column A ?_

Comment: yes, all that data is in column A only, separated by commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the correct words in a list, one word per cell, e.g in `Z2:Z20` with no blanks then you could use this formula in B1 copied down

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&Z$2:Z$20&","," "&A1&","))+0)`

Comment: Thank you both, barry and @garys-student. Both responses work, but barry's way was the simplest and most helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro **(UDF)** based solution.  Enter the following **UDF** in a standard module:

```
Public Function CorrectCount(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Long
    Dim v1 As String, v2 As String
    CorrectCount = 0
    v1 = "," & r1.Value & ","
    For Each r In r2
        v2 = "," & r.Value & ","
        If InStr(1, v1, v2) > 0 Then
            CorrectCount = CorrectCount + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

User Defined Functions **(UDFs)** are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Here is a sample in which the list of correct answers is in column **F** :

[image: demo]